# Get info from text string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string like this:

```
var info = "status=ACCEPTED&code=12345&type=CARD&id=98765";
```

How can I in a simple way get info from this string?

Example: I only want to get the "status" value from the string, in this case "ACCEPTED".

Answer (score 2):

Use the [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) like this:

```cs
var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(info);

// now you can use parsed["status"], parsed["code"], parsed["type"], and parsed["id"], which will all be strings
```

Comment: @ØyvindIsaksen No problem! You can mark your question as solved by marking my answer as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

First split by '&' then 
split by = and create dictionary out of it.

Below is a c# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
 public class Program
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program prog = new Program();
        Dictionary<String,String> output = prog.splitString("status=ACCEPTED&code=12345&type=CARD&id=98765");
        Console.WriteLine(output["status"]);

    }

    public Dictionary<string,string> splitString(string text) {
      Dictionary<string,string> output = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        if(text != null) {
            string[] keyValueArray = text.Split('&');
            foreach(string keyVal in keyValueArray) {
                string[] finalSplit = keyVal.Split('=');
                output.Add(finalSplit[0],finalSplit[1]);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or one can simply use `foreach` to create a `Disctionary` object with key/value pair. e.g.             `var info = "status=ACCEPTED&code=12345&type=CARD&id=98765";

            Dictionary<string, string> parsedData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach(string val in info.Split('&'))
            {
                parsedData.Add(val.Split('=')[0], val.Split('=')[1]);
            }`

Comment: previous code was of java so now updated it with c# code. Thanks for your feedback @MKR

Answer (score 1):

using Linq:

```
var info = "status=ACCEPTED&code=12345&type=CARD&id=98765";
var field = "status";
var value = info.Split('&').Select(i => i.Split('='))
   .Where(f => f[0].Equals(field)).Select(f => f[1]).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you like less lines of code :)

```
var info = "status=ACCEPTED&code=12345&type=CARD&id=98765";
var getInfo = new Func<string, string>(x => info.Split('&').Select(y => y.Split('=')).Where(y => y.Length > 1 && y[0] == x).Select(y => y[1]).FirstOrDefault());
```

Now simply call it as -

```
var a = getInfo("status");
var b = getInfo("id");
var c = getInfo("something");
```

Result -

> a = ACCEPTED
>
> b = 98765
>
> c = null

Concept is same, split by `&` then by `=`. I am using LINQ to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

you can take advantage of Linq `Split` then convert it to `List` to be finalized into a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

You can also create a simple model to convert it to object.

this is a simple helper method will do what you need :

```
public IDictionary<string, string> GetInfo(string info)
{
    var infoDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var str = info.Split('&').ToList();

    for (int x = 0; x < str.Count; x++)
    {
        var pair = str[x].Split('=');

        infoDic.Add(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }

    return infoDic;

}
```

usage :

```
var info = "status=ACCEPTED&code=12345&type=CARD&id=98765";

var result = GetInfo(info);

var status = result.Where(x => x.Key.ToLower() == "status")
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .First()
            .ToString();
```